# Can't style an inlineSVG within an <i>

Tags: angular, svg, sass, styles

I have the following template(angular[2])

```
<label for="draw">
    <i [inlineSVG]="../../../assets/svg/edit.svg"></i>
</label>
```

And the following Sass

```
      i {
          //works
          display: block;
          width: 33px;
          height: 28px;
          svg {
            //Not Works
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
          }
      }
```

Although the compile HTML looks good

```
<label _ngcontent-c5="" for="draw">
            <i _ngcontent-c5="" ng-reflect-inline-s-v-g="../../../assets/svg/edit.svg"><svg fill="#5B6174" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><g transform="translate(0,-952.36218)"><path style="color:#000000;enable-background:accumulate;" d="m 70.506102,970.54238 -4.2426,4.2426 11.3137,11.3137 4.242596,-4.2426 -11.313696,-11.3137 z m -7.071,7.0711 -41.7193,41.71932 11.3137,11.3137 41.7193,-41.71942 -11.3137,-11.3136 z m -43.9732,45.12222 -1.2817,11.4463 11.4464,-1.2816 -10.1647,-10.1647 z" fill="#5B6174" stroke="none" marker="none" visibility="visible" display="inline" overflow="visible"></path></g></svg></i>
          </label>
```

Also, when I edit it within the browser it works, its just like the rule ignored...
I suspect it has something to do with the Angular Styling(that it addeds its own atributes to style, so instead of styling an

```
i svg
```

it styles

```
i[_ngcontent-c4]  svg[_ngcontent-c4]
```

Why is this happening? I know from experince that you can style such SVG, I done it, but in this particular case its not working... why?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion about the style of angular wroining it was right, adding

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

after the StyleUrls in the TS of the component solved this